# How do I append records to a Sqlite table from a CSV file?

Tags: sqlite, csv

I receive several updated versions of CSV files with new lines appended at the end.

I want that the Import command only appends the records that are not in the table yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [INSERT OR IGNORE INTO](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) syntax?

Like: import your CSV into a temp table, and copy over all non-duplicate rows into your final table.  Of course, you would need to make sure that the existing rows violate some kind of UNIQUE constraint.